# App Memory Usage differs between Devices

Tags: android, memory-management, android-memory

I run my App in two different devices and check from Android Studio's Memroy tab the app's allocated memory. When the app runs in the Samsung device, the allocated memory is about 60 MB. When the app runs in the Motorola device, the allocated memory is about 40 MB.

What causes this differnce in memory allocation?

Devices:
Samsung Galaxy S4 with 5.0.1 Android Version

Motorola Moto G2 with 5.0.2 Android Version

Comment: The resolution on each device is different for a start (S4 = xxhdpi, Moto G2 xhdpi) meaning all drawables/mipmaps will have different resolution versions from your assets folders, so loaded images will take more memory - try runnning your test on same screen density phones.

Comment: This may give you hint http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Samsung has additional layer of libraries for their custom UI on Android, which will eventually lead the app to consume more memory.

Moto devices have stock/native Android.

Your variables and objects take x memory in both devices, but your UI elements take more memory in Samsung in comparison to moto device.

examplel: If stock android uses Button class, Samsung will extend the Button class to make SamsungButton class which will have additional features (like water droplet sound on click).

Comment: In my case on Nexus 5 running latest update (6.0.1) my app consumes 50MB while on Sony Xperia Z5 Compact also running 6.0.1 it consumes 25MB 
What is the cause in my case?

Comment: maybe you are using different functionalities of the app. its also related to what you are doing on app. example simple io operation might be less intensive for memory but sorting huge structures will take more memory. are you sure the apps usage was same on deviceS?

Comment: Yes they were the same I just launched main activity and waited until everything was loaded and the app went into idle state were nothing was being executed that's where memory usage went to the values I gave earlier

Comment: Might be because z5 compact has low ppi . 720 x 1280 pixels (~323 ppi pixel density). nexus 5 has better display 1080 pixels by 1920 pixels at a PPI of 445 pixels per inch. your bitmaps consume more memory in nexus 5. i bet your loading and home screen has hd images

Comment: you can also use Memory analyser tool for better insight

Comment: You are correct my home screen does have images. Perhaps thats what is causing more memory usage. Do you recommend any Memory analyzing tools?  Other than the built-in ones in Android studio?

Comment: I use eclipse MAT.  you can also look at scaling down the bitmaps and caching/ recycling them for better perfomance