# Memory allocation differs on different devices

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I tracked memory allocation of my app on 2 different devices: Samsung galaxy s2 with Android 4.1.2 and Xiaomi Redmi 1S with Android 4.4.4. 
Allocation tracking was done in the same circumstances: same app state and same tracking time(5 seconds).

Samsung galaxy s2:
[image: Samsung galaxy s2 allocation track]
Xiaomi Redmi 1s:
[image: Xiaomi Redmi 1s allocation track]

So as you can see they differs a lot. My question is - why there is such difference between these two?

Edit: it's not the same as [App Memory Usage differs between Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346721/app-memory-usage-differs-between-devices) because these allocations happened in my own methods and they have nothing to do with UI.

Comment: here is complete description...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346721/app-memory-usage-differs-between-devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App Memory Usage differs between Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346721/app-memory-usage-differs-between-devices)

Comment: @MohdSaquib i edited my question